# Ideal audio settings for voice recording

Tags: audio-recording

What would be the ideal audio settings for a voice recording app (length of audio could be long)?

In terms of:
1- Output format, mpeg_4 or 3gp or something else?
2- Encoder, like acc or amr, etc
3- Recommended Bitrate
4- Recommended Sampling rate

Comment: This is far too broad to be answerable. "Ideal"… for what? The next Disney movie voical soundtrack? A vlog… a phone call…? The output is considerably less important than the input. If you're recording on a 50 buck mic or straight into your laptop's audio input, it really won't matter what the output is.

Comment: Ideal for phones, so like good quality and small file size. Like I said this a voice recording app that uses the phone microphone for recording

Comment: Waaaay too broad a question. There are any number of voice recording apps available. What makes yours different? Why are you doing this? Answer these questions and it may help us understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It is not different from any other voice recording app. I just want to know the optimal settings to go for.